# how to create visitor counter without .text file and without value save in mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, counter, visitor-pattern

how to create visitor counter without .text file and without value save in mysql in php

a) without `$fl = fopen("count.txt","w+");` http://codebase.eu/source/code-php/ip-counter/

b) without `save db` http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/7.html

c) without `$_SESSION["visits"] = 0;`

Comment: if you are going to make visiter count for globally then you should use option (a) or option (b)

Comment: You'll need to store the usage data somewhere. For `a)` are you open to other solutions that involve creating text files to store the data (I'd advise against this but you current topic is hypothetical, no?) If you are looking for the preferred answer I'd saw that is `b)`.